# MySQL: GROUP_CONCAT where rows may not exist

Tags: mysql, null, group-concat

I have 3 tables: table1, table2 & table3

I make a select query from table1 which LEFT JOINS the other two tables. In the select I have a group_concat which takes a value from table3. Everything works well until a row with a specific row doesn't exist. The group_concat list becomes empty. Instead, I would like it to set values in the group_concat to NULL for the ones where the rows doesn't exist.

Like I said if the value in table3 exist for all the rows in table2 then it works. If not, the whole group_concat is empty.

Some "simplified" code of what I got so far:

```
SELECT 
    table1.table2Id,
    table1.dateAdded,

IF(COUNT(table2.table3Id) = COUNT(*), GROUP_CONCAT(table2.table3Id), NULL) as group1,
IF(COUNT(table3.ext) = COUNT(*), GROUP_CONCAT(table3.ext), NULL) as group2
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON
    table2.id = table1.table2Id
LEFT JOIN table3 ON
    table3.id = table2.table3Id
```

Comment: if you'll show some examples then it will help you and us better..

Comment: can you please post your structure so it will be easy to help/

Comment: You don't have a `GROUP BY` so the result will be 1 row. Do you want that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by changing

```
IF(COUNT(table3.ext) = COUNT(*), GROUP_CONCAT(table3.ext), NULL) as group2
```

to

```
GROUP_CONCAT(IFNULL(table3.ext, NULL)) as group2
```

Answer (score 0):

In your situation when you are using joins use derieved sub query in join and use IFNULL and set its default value to 0 then in the outer table this value (0) will be used if there comes null.

EDITS :

as there is no data to test you can do it like this. Use INNER JOIN instead of left join.

```
SELECT 
    table1.table2Id,
    table1.dateAdded,

IF(COUNT(table2.table3Id) = COUNT(*), GROUP_CONCAT(table2.table3Id), NULL) as group1,
IF(COUNT(table3.ext) = COUNT(*), GROUP_CONCAT(table3.ext), NULL) as group2
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON
    table2.id = table1.table2Id
INNER JOIN table3 ON
    table3.id = table2.table3Id
```

Also try using derieved sub query

```
SELECT 
    table1.table2Id,
    table1.dateAdded,
    IF(COUNT(t2.table3Id) = COUNT(*), GROUP_CONCAT(t2.table3Id), NULL) as group1,
    IF(COUNT(table3.ext) = COUNT(*), GROUP_CONCAT(table3.ext), NULL) as group2
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT 
                id,
                IFNULL(table3Id,0) as table3Id,
                table3Id
            FROM table2
            GROUP BY id table3Id
            )as t2 ON t2.id = table1.table2Id
INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.id = t2.table3Id
```